# Confused on how to do a deep copy of a doubly Linked List?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, doubly-linked-list, deep-copy

I have been trying to implement a deep copy of a doubly linked list, but I have been having trouble with it. I have to do it different several times, but I ended up  getting an address error. I just need an explanation how to do it properly.

List.H

```cpp
class List 
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();
    List(const List& c);
    List& operator= (const List& t);
private:
    List *Next;
    List *Prev;
    Node *Head;
```

List.cpp

```cpp
List::~List()
{
    Node* move = Head;
    while (move!=NULL)
    {
        Node *temp = move->Next;
        delete move;
        move = temp;
    }
}

List::List(const List& c)
{
    name = c.name;
    if (c.Head == NULL) {
        Head = NULL;
    }
    else {
        Head = new Node(*c.Head);
        Node* Current = Head;
        Node* ObjHead = c.Head;
        Node* CurrentObj = ObjHead;

        while (Current->Next!=NULL) {
            Current->Next = new Node (CurrentObj->Next->condiments);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like incorrect design to me, to begin with. Why do you have `List *prev, *next`? They should be `Node *prev, *next` instead. As it is, it is a linked list of lists, not nodes.

Comment: Well i have two doubly linked list. Node manages a doubly linked list of data. Then List manages the nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Copying linked lists is about three things:

1. Traversing the list being copied.
2. Making copies of new nodes from the originals.
3. For each new node from (2), tail-link it to the linked list.

The first of these is trivial, the second is fairly basic, but the third is the one that often tosses people for a loop. For your copy-ctor, one way to do it employs a pointer-to-pointer. This allows us to address each *pointer* in our linked list by their own addresses.

```
List::List(const List& c)
    : Head(nullptr)
    , name(c.name)
{
    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node **pp = &Head;

    for (const Node *p = c.Head; p; p = p->Next)
    {
        // make a new node, storing its address at the
        // pointer obtained by dereference of `pp`. the
        // first iteration that will be the Head member.
        *pp = new Node(*p);
        (*pp)->Prev = prev;
        prev = *pp;

        // now just advance `pp` to point to the `Next`
        // member of the node we just hung on the list.
        pp = &(*pp)->Next; 
    }
    *pp = nullptr; // terminate the list.
}
```

This assumes you're `Node` class supports copy-construction (it had better). but that's all it takes. From that, you can use the [copy/swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/1322972) to manufacture your copy-assignment operator and have a basic rule-of-three compliance list class.

Comment: my copy constructor is working fine now but, the copy assignment is where im having some issues. Im trying to do it without the copy/swap method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much better to have an `Insert()` and call that from the copy constructor?

Comment: @TanveerBadar no. With the only info I've been given about this list there is no tail pointer. `Insert` would therefore have to iterate-to-end with each insertion, and therefore turn a copy-ctor operation into O(N^2) rather than the *very* trivial O(N) seen above. if you want to get "better", it would be "better" to not do any of this madness and just use `std::list` in the first place.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah im sure its easy to do with std::List but i need to implement this without it or any other container. So to my understanding  I need to also traverse through the list in the copy assignment operator also.

Comment: @Jay, you need to implement one, yes. You don't need to necessarily do this sort of thing. [See the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/1322972) in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dummy head to begin with. Once the deep copying is done, you can set `head` to the next of the dummy head and delete the dummy head. You also won't have to check for `if (c.Head == NULL)` this way.

```
    Node *ptr1, *ptr2;
    head = ptr1 = new Node();
    ptr2 = c.head;
    while (ptr2)
    {
        ptr1->next = new Node(*ptr2);
        ptr1 = ptr1->next;
        ptr2 = ptr2->next;
    }

    Node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete temp;
```

Comment: @ lucieon when i run it and try to get the data from a node i get an exception thrown. read acess violation. *this* was nullptr. Not sure why thats happening

Comment: I don't see a case where this would try to read a `nullptr`. Try making the function `const` like this `List& operator= (const List& t) const;`. Also make sure you initialize the pointers to `nullptr` in the default constructor of `Node` class.

Comment: @luceion Yeah i made sure pointers were all set to nullptr. i pretty sure the issue is somewhere in the copy assignment.

Comment: Try running it through a debugger.